# MySQL grant privileges has no effect

Tags: mysql, permissions

I've executed the following queries:

```
GRANT USAGE ON my_db.* TO my_user@127.0.0.1 IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
GRANT ALL ON my_db.* TO my_user@127.0.0.1;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON my_db.* TO my_user@127.0.0.1;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

But they don't show up.

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR my_user@127.0.0.1;
```

results in

```
GRANT USAGE ON my_db.* TO my_user@127.0.0.1 IDENTIFIED BY '*123...';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_db.* TO my_user@127.0.0.1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Aley,

```
GRANT ALL ON my_db.* TO my_user@127.0.0.1;
```

is a superset of:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON my_db.* TO my_user@127.0.0.1;
```

So the last one is superfluous. You must understand that `SHOW GRANTS` do not show every grant query that you executed, and that in some specific cases, it may not show all grants for a user. That is something that can be very confusing in MySQL.

Also, another tip is that you do not need `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` if you only use `GRANT/CREATE/DROP` keywords, only if you modify directly the `mysql.*` tables.